# Embedding text in curved surface

Tags: modifiers, shaders, topology

I've been trying to create a keycap, with a slightly translucent letter embedded and lit up by an emmision texture. I've mostly been succesful but i've hit a brick wall, I used the boolean operation to embed the extruded letter which left me with a lot of ngons. This causes weird shading issues, I know they are caused by bad topology but I  just don't know HOW to fix the topology to remove these shading problems. If anyone has any ideas on how to fix this, please let me known. Thanks

A few images to clarify the situation :

Mesh  :
[image: KeyCapMesh]

Shading issues :
[image: KeyCapShadingIssues]

Rendered result :
[image: KeyCapRender]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure how you want it to look like, but if you add a remesh modifier, you will get:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm trying to get rid of the shading issues caused by the ngons, it's not visible during the render since it's barely visible (It can only really be seen when using a MatCap). It's not really an issue with this render but i'm just trying to find out how I can prevent this bad topology from happening in the future. I'm not sure if you applied the remesh on the keycap or the text, i've tried it out on both but it doesn't seem to help. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

I think your main problem are the normals, that is what looks bad, you could improve topology too but what I would suggest is to keep in place a copy of the original object -before cutting the B- and transfer the normals to the new mesh... for this you can use a transfer data modifier with a vertex group as a mask, then apply it if you want

about topology, having a better cookie-cut object, maybe with a bit lower resolution could help I guess

[image: data transfer modifier]

Answer (score 0):

I think the main factor is the topology.

In order for smooth-shading to interpolate normals in a way that simulates curvature on underlying polygonal geometry, it must have data-points to interpolate *between*, that are a reasonable  approximation of a curved surface. If your polygonal surface is split in only one direction, the smoothing has nothing to go by along the long straight edges, resulting in artefacts:

[image]

If the polygonal surface is split in both directions, the smoothing interpolation has something to get its teeth into:

[image]

This is *before* repairing the Boolean mesh, or pulling any tricks like transferring normals from an intact version of the surface.

[image]